# Laravel - where >= not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a database entry with this lines of code:

```
$hoy = date('YYYY-MM-DD');
$stay = Stay::where('guest', '=', $id )
                    ->where('indate', '<=', $hoy )
                    ->where('outdate', '>=', $hoy )
                    ->get( array( 'id', 'room', 'bed', 'guest', 'booking', 'indate', 'outdate' ) );
```

The thing is, if I remove the `outdate >= $hoy` line, it works. But with it, it doesn't.
The line i'm trying to retrieve has it's outdate set to `2015-12-02`, so it should return it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should give more info. What is `$hoy`? What entry should it retrieve and what are its values?

Comment: you can check  the query directly with mysql to see where is your error.. you get something like select * from stays where guest = $id and indate<= $hoy and outdate >= $hoy;

Comment: In phpmyadmin works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is your problem:

```
$hoy = date('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If you want to generate a date like 2015-12-02, you should do this instead:

```
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

This query expects both conditions to be true.

If you want to return when either one is true you should try `->orwhere`.

If you are looking for both to be true you need to keep in mind that if there are timestamps on the date the query of `<=` will only find dates with a timestamp of `00:00:00` for the requested date.

Comment: I need both to be true. And they are.
Actually, if I remove the indate where, still doesn't work.